# VBA Code Does Not run, error on defining Workbook and Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a problem-solving solution.

I am trying to run the following code, but I always get "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range.".

The problem is in this line: Set source = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(2)

```
Sub TesteNum()
Dim appExcel As Application
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim i, k, n, userAns As Integer
Dim timeCount, timeTotal As Double
Dim source, target As Worksheets

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

If IsEmpty(pathFolder) = True Then
    Call GetFilePath
    Else
    userAns = MsgBox("Encontrado caminho do ficheiro, quer selecionar outro ficheiro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
    If userAns = vbYes Then
        Call GetFilePath
    Else
    End If
End If

'create new excel application object
Set appExcel = New Application

'set the applications visible property to false
appExcel.Visible = True

'open the workbook with data
Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathFolder)

Set source = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(2)
Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'numRowsImport = Worksheets("NewRawData").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

numRowsImport = source.Range("A" & source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For k = 3 To numRowsImport
    timeCount = source.Cells(k, 9).Value
    timeTotal = timeTotal + timeCount
Next k

'MsgBox "O valor total é " & Format(timeTotal, "h:mm"), vbOKOnly, "Caminho do ficheiro"

target.Range("U11").Value = timeTotal

'close the workbooks
objWorkbook.Close

'close the application
appExcel.Quit

MsgBox "O valor total é " & timeTotal, vbOKOnly, "Caminho do ficheiro"



'ErrorHandle:

'MsgBox "Erro. Contacte o administrador."

End Sub
```

Can you guys help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. What is `filename`?

Answer (score 0):

you declaration

```
Dim source, target As Worksheets
```

doesn't declare 'source' as a worksheet. It declares source as a variant and target as a worksheet. Seperate the declarations.

Comment: Actually, should be `Worksheet` too, not `Worksheets`.

Comment: Yup for sure. And we still don't know if 'filename' is a string or what it's referencing. So that might be throwing it out of range too.

Comment: filename is a string. It is declared as this: Public fileName as String.

Comment: I tried that, and it does not work. It still declares Run-time error 9 on the line "Set source = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(2)".

Comment: have you tried setting target and source the same way? Or maybe using the sheetname directly? other than that, the only thing I can think of is that fileName isn't taking the string you want it to.